# immutable string class?

Tags: java

if we have these statements:

```
String S1 = "AAA";
S1 = "aaa";
```

this mean that the original value assigned to a specific property has't changed.(because the string class is immutable and S1 is an interned object).

now...
if we have the following statements:

```
String S1 = new String("AAA");
S1="aaa";
```

this mean that the original value assigned to a specific property in string class has changed.(because the string class is immutable and S1 is not interned object)

is my understanding right?

Comment: Easy to try and see S1 does not change in either case.

Answer (score 4):

No, `String` object is immutable under any circumstances. When you call `new String("foo")` this simply creates another one string with content of passed. So don't do this.

EDIT:
In the second case `S1` isn't interned but this doesn't cancel its immutability. So `String` assignment always doesn't change left object but simply rewrites reference.

Comment: The _only_ thing that changes is that `S1` points to a different `String` object.  You have not, and cannot, modify the `String` itself.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable.
That means that an instance of String cannot change.
You're creating new variable to refer to a different but still immutable String instance.

it allows for changes to the string to branch off the original string in a change list sort of method

```
String s = new String();
```

An empty String object ("") is created. And the variable s refers to that object.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to other answers,

String constructor that takes String object is a design flaw(It doesn't make sense to create an immutable instance twice) and is deprecated. Don't use it.